# google cloud storage python API error

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am using python API to download file from GCS and getting error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "storage-sample.py", line 150, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "storage-sample.py", line 128, in main
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 548, in next_chunk
    resp, content = http.request(self._uri, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 490, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.6.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1593, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.6.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1335, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.6.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1318, in _conn_request
    content = response.read()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 522, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 565, in _read_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(value))
MemoryError
```

This error occurs only with one file that I am trying to download from GCS. The same code works perfectly fine with any other file in GCS. Is it because the file is corrupted or something like that?

Comment: How big is the object?

Comment: I think the client library is trying to read the entire thing into memory at once.

Comment: Well I ran some test keeping that in mind. I tried to download 12.4GB of object in chunck size of (1024 *1024 *1024) bytes when system has about 328MB memory available. And that object downloaded perfectly fine.